# Channels Information

Tags: channel, fields

In the control panel, you can set channels access for users.

In the frontend, I want to get the channels data a user has access to and the fields data it can view.

I am not talking about the channel entries data. I am talking about the channel data themselves.

Is there a way to get this information? Are there addons for these feature?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to run a query to get the data. You should be able to run the following against the member_group field of the member.

```
SELECT exp_channels.channel_title, exp_channel_fields.field_label, exp_channel_fields.field_name, exp_channel_fields.field_type, exp_channel_member_groups.channel_id FROM exp_channels, exp_channel_fields, exp_channel_member_groups WHERE exp_channel_member_groups.group_id = '6' AND exp_channel_member_groups.channel_id = exp_channels.channel_id AND exp_channels.field_group = exp_channel_fields.group_id
```

So in EE, run a exp:query like this maybe: (Should at least get you going)

```
Member Group : {member_group}<br>

<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Channel</th>
        <th>Field</th>
        <th>Type</th>
    <tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
        {exp:query sql="
            SELECT channel_title, field_label, field_name, field_type
                FROM exp_channels a
                JOIN exp_channel_member_groups b on b.channel_id = a.channel_id
                JOIN exp_channel_fields c on c.group_id = a.field_group
                WHERE b.group_id = '7'
        "}
            <tr>
                <td>{channel_title}</td>
                <td>{field_label} - {field_name}</td>
                <td>{field_type}</td>
            </tr>
        {/exp:query}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Of course, you'll have to figure a way to get your member's {group_id} into where '7' is now.

Comment: What about the fields? Viewing of the fields can be limited by member group, right?

Comment: Yes. You would just need to join the tables you need and render out the results.